# Expresso Store checkout tag - ACT id not being inserted into form

Tags: expresso-store, checkout, action

This is a weird problem.

I have an existing site which uses Expresso:Store and has been working OK. Now suddenly, I am seeing intermittent problems adding items to the cart.

It seems that the add to cart form doesn't have an ACT Id inserted into the hidden field. Instead it's getting the value {AID:Store:act_checkout}.

My client says that this is random and doesn't happen all the time. However I wonder if they are just viewing cached pages.

Has anyone encountered this problem or have any idea what may be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, after puzzling over this for a while I came up with the answer just after posting this question.

It seems that this problem is caused by having template/page caching turned on. If the page is cached then future calls to it don't insert the ACT ID into the form.